# How give the admin system user in partner Business Manager permission for client's business?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am following this guide [Business On Behalf Of](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/guides/on-behalf-of) and in the step 2 Im getting this 400 error with the text **Your access token doesn't have permission to access this client business.** The access token is from the admin system user. How am I supposed to give permissions to the admin system user? which it was created in the partner account of which I am the administrator. I have not found documentation of how to do it. Also the client business belongs to a test user[image]

Comment: could you figure this out @YosefMac?